# number of DAGs with maximum number of edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a set of $n$ vertices, I am wondering how many DAGs out there with maximum number of edges ? In other words, the number of DAGs where every DAG has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ edges.

Comment: A partial order with all edges present defines a total order.  There are $n!$ possible total orders on $n$ elements.

Comment: These are called *transitive tournaments.* In fact, *up to isomorphism*, there is only one for each $n$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx please make it as an answer. Thanks